# How to open flutter application from url?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, deep-linking

For example, i have case in my flutter app when user can recover his password.
In that case user will receive link on e-mail, and i want by clicking on that link, my flutter app will open, and route to specific screen.

Comment: You can use Firebase Dynamic Links , I wrote a post about that : https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-firebase-dynamic-link-6f1b79278ce0

Comment: @diegoveloper thanks! This is what i actually try to find

Comment: There is a nice plugin for this, https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links it also has a detailed explanation on how you need to configure iOS and Android for it to work (which is the hardest part imho); another nice source of information is [this blog post](https://medium.com/flutter-community/deep-links-and-flutter-applications-how-to-handle-them-properly-8c9865af9283)

Answer (score 17):

You'll want to view this from the perspective of: *How do I open my iOS/Android app from a URL,* ie. **App Deep Linking**.

They each have their own respective implementations:

- [android/app-links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links)
- [apple/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content)

Or you can go with more comprehensive SDKs that are capable of doing both for you:

- [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links)
- [Branch.io Deep Linking](https://branch.io/what-is-deep-linking/)

Answer (score 6):

So here , you must use a `dynamic link`.
The best solution is the use of **[Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links)** .

**One of the advantages of Firebase Dynamic Links:**  Convert mobile web users to native app users

> With Dynamic Links, you can seamlessly transition users from your
> mobile website to the equivalent content within your app. And because
> the links survive the app install process, even new users can pick up
> where they left off on your mobile site without missing a beat.

[image]

Another solution is to switch to native solutions:  **[Android](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links)** and **[iOS](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content).**

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to use any package to just launch app from url (if
you don't want to get data from link)

```
          <!-- App Link sample -->

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myapp.flutter.com" android:pathPrefix="/success" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myapp.flutter.com" android:pathPrefix="/failure" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Deep Link sample -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Add optional android:host to distinguish your app
                     from others in case of conflicting scheme name -->
                <data android:scheme="app" android:host="success" />
                <data android:scheme="app" android:host="failure" />
                <!-- <data android:scheme="sample" /> -->
            </intent-filter>
```

- Just copy and paste in AndroidManifest.xml below code and launch in
  browser "app://success" or "app://failure".
- Remember **launch** "app://success" or "app://failure" **not search**

Answer (score 2):

You can use [app_links](https://pub.dev/packages/app_links), that supports Android App Links, Deep Links, iOs Universal Links and Custom URL schemes handler (desktop included) for Android, iOS, macOS, web and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Dynamic Links is no longer recommended, [as per 2023](https://firebase.google.com/support/dynamic-links-faq?hl=en&authuser=2)

[image]

You may proceed with [App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links?authuser=2) or  [Universal links](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing-apps-and-websites-to-link-to-your-content)