# How to open flutter app from any web browser?

Tags: flutter

i know we can open android app using **Android Deep Links** and produce result as we want. But is there a way to open flutter app from web browser? 
[this is what that i found at this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770563/how-to-open-flutter-application-from-url)

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

You can't call the deep link URL from the web browser's search bar. First, you need to create an HTML page. Then you can click the link. It will work.

## More details

In my case, I created an HTML file with a deep link and send it to my email.

**HTML file**

```
<a href="myapp://test">Open my app</a>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:host="test"
        android:scheme="myapp" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Flutter app, permissions are configured in exactly the same way, as the corresponding native configurations.
Android :

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data
    android:scheme="poc"
    android:host="deeplink.flutter.dev" />
</intent-filter>
```

IOS:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
<string>Editor</string>
<key>CFBundleURLName</key>
<string>deeplink.flutter.dev</string>
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>poc</string>
</array>
</dict>
</array>
```

[refer this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/deep-links-and-flutter-applications-how-to-handle-them-properly-8c9865af9283)

Comment: how can i get request that is coming from browser?