# how to redirect from web to app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-webview

hello I have a link in my app that opens the browser I want my app to open after a certain button pressed in the browser
I know a plugin named inAppWebView that can support this...I don't know how especially when it is opened in an external browser like Chrome

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770563/how-to-open-flutter-application-from-url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open flutter application from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770563/how-to-open-flutter-application-from-url)

Comment: not exactly but yes it is correct thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way of opening apps from the web is with the use of app links. In Flutter, you can use [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/receive) with the [firebase_dynamic_links](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links) plugin. Other ways of doing so is with the use of [app_links](https://pub.dev/packages/app_links) plugin.

Comment: For future readers: Firebase Dynamic Links is deprecated and will stop working on Aug 2025